# gcloud invalid choice 'preview' error

Tags: android, maven, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am trying to build and deploy the "playchat" Android app using Firebase and the App Engine Flexible Environment.

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible

I am getting a "(gcloud) Invalid choice: 'preview'" error when I try to build and deploy to the cloud with the following command.

```
mvn clean gcloud:deploy -Dgcloud.gcloud_directory=/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk -X
```

I am using the latest apache-maven (3.3.9) and gcloud (148.0.0).

It looks like there may be an open issue with the gcloud-maven-plugin.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-maven-plugin/issues/92

Can someone please recommend which versions of these tools will play nice together?  This has been an unpleasant first start with gcloud so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, it appears that documentation might be slightly out of data. The gcloud-maven-plugin has been deprecated. I've filed a bug against the reference project so they may address it : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/firebase-appengine-backend/issues/6